# On RedHat OS, I am getting different behavior on mounting NFS server

Tags: linux, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux, nfs

I am trying to mount nfs server using below command on different RHEL oses:

mount -t nfs4 -o "vers=3" IP:/NFS_share /NFS_share/

Whenever I tried to mount it over different RHEL 7.4 os, nfs share path is mounted using nfs version 4.1, while on other RHEL oses it is mounted using nfs version 3.

Can someone tell me, why I am getting different behaviour on it?